# Search Queries with 0 Number of Uses

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

Our store has a lot of Search Queries with "Number of Uses" listed as 0.  It seems illogical that Magento would track unused search terms.

What does this mean? / Why is Magento doing this?

EDIT:
"Number of uses" is listed in the admin: catalog > search terms -- open any search term. See image.
[image: search term]

For anyone who might stumble on this later, I now suspect "number of uses 0" means that someone entered a search term but didn't click enter to initiate the search.

Comment: Where did you find "number of uses"? I only find `catalogsearch_query.num_results` which is not the uses but the results and it makes sense, that it is 0 :-)